# "Body" of a post request always in unicode

Tags: node.js, post, https

If I make a POST request to a specific server using a Chrome plugin, I can see the "response body" comes back just fine in a JSOn format.

However when I try to do this with either "request" or "https.request", the "body" comes back as unicode which I can't seem to decipher. Anyone know how I can the body to come back as regular JSON, or how I could decipher this unicode? I tried a few stackoverflow solutions to decipher the unicode but no luck.

raw body:

```
��RPP�M-.NLOUR�RP�I,�K�P�,V��/QHL.�,KU��J�O�*─
                                                                 �⎽�����wt�
                                                                           ⎽U��┬�>H ---
```

If I do this: JSON.stringify(body, null, 4)

```
 "\┤001°�\␉\┤0000\┤0000\┤0000\┤0000\┤0000\┤0000\┤0000��RPP�M-.NLOUR�RP�I,�K�P�,V��/QHL.�,KU�\┤0001�J�O�*─\°�⎽����\┤000°�┬├\┤000␊�\°⎽U�\┤0005\┤0000�┬�>H\┤0000\┤0000\┤0000"
```

And here's the two code snippets I use to try and make POST requests:

```
request({
      'url': 'https://api.nike.com/launch/entries/v2',
      'method': 'POST',
      'json': entriesPayload,
      'headers': {
        'authorization': authId,

        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8"
      },
    },
...
```

and:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'api.nike.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/launch/entries/v2',
    method: 'POST',
    json: entriesPayload,
 headers: {
   'authorization': authId,

   "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
 }
  };
  var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });
  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
```

---

Also I get some real weird stuff happening after I make the request, in my IDE's logs. This is what shows up - it like translates everything into some different symbols (the last 3 lines are how I restarted my nodejs server).

```
       "⎻⎺⎼├": 443,
            "␤⎺⎽├┼▒└␊": "▒⎻␋.┼␋┐␊.␌⎺└",
            "␤▒⎽␤": ┼┤┌┌,
            "⎽␊▒⎼␌␤": ┼┤┌┌,
            "─┤␊⎼≤": ┼┤┌┌,
            "⎻▒├␤┼▒└␊": "/┌▒┤┼␌␤/␊┼├⎼␋␊⎽/┴2",
            "⎻▒├␤": "/┌▒┤┼␌␤/␊┼├⎼␋␊⎽/┴2",
            "␤⎼␊°": "␤├├⎻⎽://▒⎻␋.┼␋┐␊.␌⎺└/┌▒┤┼␌␤/␊┼├⎼␋␊⎽/┴2"
        £,
        "└␊├␤⎺␍": "POST",
        "␤␊▒␍␊⎼⎽": π
            "▒┤├␤⎺⎼␋≥▒├␋⎺┼": "B␊▒⎼␊⎼ ␊≤J␤␉G␌␋O␋JSU≥I1N␋I⎽I└├⎻ZCI6I┘␌2YWI1NT␤┐LWM┬ZTM├NGV␤Y␋05MT┌┘LTJ┐Y┘A3Y┘F┘N2N␤MHN⎻Z≤J9.␊≤J0␌┼V≥␍CI6MTA┬LCJ⎻YXQ␋O┘E1NDM2N≥␌┬ODA⎽I└V4␌CI6MTU0M≥Y4MDY4MC┬␋▒XN≥I┘⎺␋␉2F1␍G±≤YWN┘I␋┬␋▒┼R⎻I┘⎺␋ZGV␋MTZ┘M2Q├YT±│OS00OTE3LWF␤MD┐├NWV␤N≥R└M┘U┬MWM4I␋┬␋␉GF0I┘⎺│NTQ≥N┘␌3MD±┬LCJ␤␍WQ␋O␋J┘␉20┤␉└┌⎼ZS5┐▒W␍⎻␍GF⎽I␋┬␋␌3V␋I┘⎺␋Y29├L└5⎻▒2U┤Y29├␉WV≤Y2U┤␌25⎼␌┼M┤␍2V␋I␋┬␋␌2J0I┘⎺␋␉└┌⎼ZT⎻␤␌HA␋LCJ≥Y3A␋O┌⎽␋Y29├␉WV≤Y2U␋XS┬␋␌HJ┤I┘⎺␋M└I≥M≥J┐Y└U├MWE1Y≤00ZWJ┐LT┐0Z└Y├MGU┬N≥V┘OGV┘NGQ│I␋┬␋␌HJ0I┘⎺␋␉└┌⎼ZT⎻┬␉HV≥I┼0.I┴▒┘└U2W≤␉__┬AD└J±⎻Z≥␉␋-VVUV┘H⎽⎼EI├┼T┌␍1I9°┬OSL▒┬┤8≥0Z3┐C␍␊G⎽␊O≤│≥␌␉3RB┌GKXV┤SDRDH±IYZ␉H1X⎼5␉Q-┼R≥└┬I␤│␉M0─I⎺R┤␋␍␤▒I␋├NC␍⎺G±6⎺XQ␋°R┴W5␍⎺SZ┼⎻4YR2TN6U␍9Q≥⎻61NS⎺⎻F␌2V13NJ└0P7│K5-09⎻▒1│6P␍M≤┼⎽IWF─␤II⎼G≤K┘HO⎻BV└┌┤␋A≥°┼AF┤K1GC┌ZGD⎺TC␋8⎻JY_⎺HI-E8D±M┐O4KSN⎻H97KLHO-┴Z│2┬YLJ2°␉0⎼F┐D≤≤└A␍K⎼9┴┬┤9┼│XF␍⎼≥⎽┘22≤39KD⎻-⎽⎻R┐I⎺MD2▒└␋┼L1CA│8─-␉L│DY└┬GQ02C├I0─┘±",
            "A␌␌␊⎻├": "▒⎻⎻┌␋␌▒├␋⎺┼/┘⎽⎺┼, ├␊│├/⎻┌▒␋┼, */*",
            "C⎺┼├␊┼├-T≤⎻␊": "▒⎻⎻┌␋␌▒├␋⎺┼/┘⎽⎺┼;␌␤▒⎼⎽␊├=┤├°-8",
            "␌⎺┼├␊┼├-┌␊┼±├␤": 575
        £
    £
£

[┼⎺␍␊└⎺┼] ⎼␊⎽├▒⎼├␋┼± ␍┤␊ ├⎺ ␌␤▒┼±␊⎽...
[┼⎺␍␊└⎺┼] ⎽├▒⎼├␋┼± ◆┼⎺␍␊ ▒⎻⎻.┘⎽◆
E│⎻⎼␊⎽⎽ ⎽├▒⎼├␊␍ ⎺┼ ⎻⎺⎼├ 3000
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @JanithKasun I edited it to post the code

Comment: Is there a possibility that you might use other libraries, like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: I am using request, as seen in the first code snippet that i'm using @JanithKasun

Comment: What is `entriesPayload`? In case it's a file - please post the code that reads it.

Comment: You need to confirm that the server response is properly encoded. Most likely problem on "their side".

Comment: @yeya It's just a JSON object, like "let entriesPayload = { "locale": locale" }". When I change it to just "{}", I also get back the buggy response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response body is not unicode encoded, but GZIP encoded (compressed data). We can check if a response is compressed with the Content-Encoding header:

```
var encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];
```

`https` doesn't unzip the response body automatically like a browser does, and so you get all those strange characters instead of a JSON string. However, we can use the built-in [`zlib`](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) library and decdode the response to a string.

```
const https = require('https');
const zlib = require('zlib');

var options = {
    hostname: 'api.nike.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/launch/entries/v2',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'my-token',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
};
var data = JSON.stringify({});

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    var encoding =  res.headers['content-encoding'];
    console.log('code:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('encoding:', encoding);

    deflate = zlib.createGunzip();
    res.pipe(deflate);
    deflate.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log('data: ' + chunk.toString());
    });
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Comment: Hi t.m.adam, hope you are doing well. I would be very glad if you have chance to give [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559894/cant-produce-some-customized-output-after-scraping-data-from-a-webpage) a go. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The chrome plugin that you're using to POST is probably setting the content-type correctly, while your regular request from your server isn't.

Can you change your request so it includes

```
request({
   'url': externalUrl,
   'method': 'POST',
   'json': entriesPayload,
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, my original question is edited to what I have it as now. My chrome plugin has the "application/json;charset=utf-8" by default, but when I put that in, everything is bugged in the unicode. However when I put in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", I don't get a bugged response, but the external server brings back a 404 response.

Also when I don't have an 'authorization' at all, the external server brings back a proper error response and I can read it. Just not sure why certain errors are coming back in unicode which I can't read.

Comment: I also put in another weird thing I'm encountering, and I put that at the end of the original question up above