# Can't produce some customized output after scraping data from a webpage

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping

I'm trying to append data to a dictionary while scraping the same from a webppage. The output that I'm having at this moment is not how I wish to arrange them. This is the [webpage](https://elllo.org/english/grammar/L1-01-AimeeTodd-Intros-BeVerb.htm).

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://elllo.org/english/grammar/L1-01-AimeeTodd-Intros-BeVerb.htm'
data = []

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("#transcript p"):
    d = {}

    if "Aimee:" in item.text:
        d['Aimee'] = item.text.replace("Aimee:","").strip()

    elif "Todd:" in item.text:
        d['Todd'] = item.text.replace("Todd:","").strip()

    data.append(d)

pprint(data)
```

Output I'm getting like:

```
[{'Aimee': 'So Todd, where are you from?'},
 {'Todd': "I am from the U.S., I am from San Francisco. It's on the west "
          'coast.'},
 {'Aimee': 'And what do you do?'},
 {'Todd': "I'm an English teacher. Also, I create Elllo. I work on Elllo a "
          'lot.'}
```

Expected output:

```
[{'Aimee': 'So Todd, where are you from?','Todd': "I am from the U.S., I am from San Francisco. It's on the west "
          'coast.'},

 {'Aimee': 'And what do you do?','Todd': "I'm an English teacher. Also, I create Elllo. I work on Elllo a "
          'lot.'},
```

> How can I produce the second output?

Comment: How would you decide when a conversation is finished?  I will post an answer that shows how to get this effect, but it's not really a robust solution.

Comment: Instead of `data = []` I can use `data = {}` ,`data['Conversation'] = []` in order to produce an output which will represent when the conversation is finished.

Comment: That lets you store a conversation, but it doesn't say anything about how you can KNOW when the conversation is finished.  Will all conversations always have one question and one response?  If so, then I suspect my answer is optimal.

Comment: Sorry to not have been able to understand your question. Yep, the conversation is one question and one response basis.

Comment: As an alternative to Tim's answer, you could store the transcript tags in a list `l` and iterate it in steps of two - `for i in range(0, len(l) - 1, 2):`. Then you'll have Aimee's convrsation in `l[i]` and Tom's in `l[i+1]`.

Comment: That definitely solves the issue @t.m.adam. If I'm not wrong [this is](https://pastebin.com/YC00dNvM) something what you meant, right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
d = {}
for item in soup.select("#transcript p"):

    if "Aimee:" in item.text:
        d['Aimee'] = item.text.replace("Aimee:","").strip()

    elif "Todd:" in item.text:
        d['Todd'] = item.text.replace("Todd:","").strip()
        data.append(d)
        d = {}

pprint(data)
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but ain't there a better way.